# upload photo to facebook from Amazon S3 (or generic URL)

Tags: facebook

I'd like to create an application that uploads photos to my facebook page from an online location but without having to download and reupload them (facebook should download them directly form S3 public url). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/:

> *“You can also publish a photo by providing a `url` param with the photo's URL.”*